# Routing - RDP to a VM on a home server from remote laptop via WireGuard tunnel

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop, routing, wireguard

Trying to remote desktop to a windows VM on a home server from remote windows laptop via WireGuard tunnel.
Trying piece it together from searches, am connected on VPN but now stuck.  Please can you help?

Laptop -> WG -> Internet -> Home Router -> Home Server -> WG -> VM on home server bridged with its nic, but WG and VM/home network are different subnets.

```
Home
Router          192.168.1.1
Server          192.168.1.5 with Wireguard and VM
VM bridged      192.168.1.10
WG Server       10.8.1.1


Remote Laptop tethered to mobile
192.168.50.200 with Wireguard client
WG Client 10.8.1.2
```

Port forwarding on home router has me connected from laptop to home server on Wireguard (8.1.1).

But now need to connect to the VM (168.1.10) on the server (168.1.5) at home.

Added the VM IP to AllowedIP's in Wireguard Client. Which has created the route on laptop:
192.168.1.10 255.255.255.255 10.8.1.2

But when pinging VM i get Request timed out.

Tracert of VM ip on laptop shows hop1 as 10.8.1.1

So its hit the end of the tunnel, but not routed to the VM.

This is where my mind has scrambled and please can you advise whats next?

I tried adding a route on home server (168.1.5) to vm (168.1.10) via WG (8.1.1)
route add 192.168.1.10/32 10.8.1.1

Tried then adding a route on the VM to the WG server
route add 10.8.1.0/24 192.168.1.10

Disabled all firewalls.

Request timed out ping from laptop to VM
Destination host unreachable from VM to laptop.

Added a static route on home router (168.1.1)
10.8.1.0 192.168.1.5

Same result.  Am stuck.

Trying to avoid ICS primarily....also avoid router changes if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: IP(v4) (not port) forwarding needs to be enabled *and* allowed (in its firewall, if set up) on the WG server. Make sure the VM have return route for the WG subnet / client, if SNAT (a.k.a. IP masquerading) for the client is not set up / desired.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I set the WG server to allow IP forwarding by
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters."
IP Enable Router = 1 (from 0)

Then added a route on the VM back to WG subnet via host adapter

Thank you very much for the reply.  I can't see where to mark this as answered.